# Simultaneous OTG + Charging Capability

Tags: charging, usb-on-the-go

I'm working on a hobby project to stick a tablet in a car to replace the factory head unit. For this, I need to connect the reverse camera to the tablet (via USB, using something like an [EasyCAP adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W1KX2SO)), while the tablet being charged.

So far, I found that [Lava SimulCharge](http://lavalink.com/samsung-tablet-adapters/tl-002/) adapter claims to do this. Although it's very picky about [the devices it works](http://lavalink.com/samsung-tablet-adapters-support/compatibility-list/) with. (Exclusively a few Samsung Galaxy tabs with strict OS versions and even cable lengths)

I would like to know what other alternatives I have which can do this. (Prefer not being locked down only to the LAVA supported tablets, as they're quite expensive for my purpose.)

Is it a Samsung only feature? (seems like *most* Windows tablets support this out of the box across a number of OEMs. But haven't seen any Android device that isn't Samsung supporting this.)

Can I check which tablets have the support?

I prefer to do this without rooting the device.

Comment: You could buy a cheap docking station and split it like here http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/accessories/xperia-p-sony-smartdock-dk20-ion-t2293849

Comment: I did some research and seems like not may tablets have docks with USB nowadays.

Comment: Yes.. But lower end Chinese ones often have - don't recollect names and that may fit the budget as well. Apart from that, there are too many factors involved to say with confidence " yes, this should work"