# UVC/UTV007/HTV600 driver support for Galaxy Tab S2 or Galaxy Tab E

Tags: usb, video-streaming

I'm planning to connect a reverse camera to an android tablet.

I am using the famous EasyCAP device to get the analog RCA signal to USB input.

I have tried this with a [few](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vertile.fpv3d) [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=labsp.android.viewer) and turns out they rely on a kernel mode driver which may or may not be included in a given device.

My Nexus 5X works well, but my Galaxy Tab A 7" (2016) doesn't seem to have it. ([Go FPV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vertile.fpv3d) app says it can't find the driver)

So my question is, is there a list of device models that I can refer to, to find a device that has the driver? My target is to use a Galaxy Tab S2 or a Galaxy Tab E (due to [another constraint for my project](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155811/simultaneous-otg-charging-capability))

How can I find out which of these 2 devices will include the kernel mode driver I need?

Another option is to use the popular [EasyCAP Viewer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easycap.viewer) which is paid, since [Arksine's Easycam project here](https://github.com/Arksine/Easycam#faq) suggests that app uses a user-mode driver which doesn't rely on the kernel mode driver to be present. I'm not sure whether it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It's been a while and I haven't seen any answers, so I'm gonna post my approach and findings. If someone has an answer, please post here and I will accept it.***

---

So far, I couldn't find a list of devices that supports the UVC driver.

If you do have a device and wondering it would support UVC, you can download [Go FPV App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vertile.fpv3d) which will show whether you have a UVC driver or not on a given device upon launch. (You do not need to connect the UVC device to get this.)

If you're using the [EasyCAP Viewer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easycap.viewer), you do not need the driver. I can confirm it doesn't rely on the kernel driver.

If you're writing an app that requires input from a UVC adapter, this [GitHub project](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Just to muddy the water a little. nothing about using Ezy cap is so simple. I have an OTG cable between my EzyCap unit and a Samsung Galaxy tab 10. When I plug in the OTG cable to the tablet the power led on the EzyCap lights up. On the tablet, it works fine. If however I use the same OTG cable to two different (cheap) mobile phones, when I plug in the OTG cable the power LED on the Ezy cap does not light up. I tried another OTG cable and also tried splitting an OTG cable to supply external power to the Ezycap. Simply doesnt work on either phone.

Ive tried a lot of different apps including those you list. The only way to know if your phone or tablet is compatible is to try it!

Sorry its not good news, but its the facts.